# How to place cursor to certain EditText box?

Tags: android

My XML contains Five `EditText` box and One Button.  My cursor is now pointed to the First `EditText` box. How can I click a button to place the cursor automaticly to Third `EditText` box.

Thank you!

Comment: fastest answer ever given.. didn't bother finishing my answer lol

Comment: Thanks. I agree `editText.requestFocus();`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

on your button's `onClick()` put..

```
thirdEditText.requestFocus();
```

Something like,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            thirdEditText.requestFocus(); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: + 1 for understand his question properly .

Answer (score 2):

> editText3.requestFocus();

add in onClick method of button.

Comment: + 1 for understand his question properly and give the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `requestFocus()` method to gain focus.

Or put < requestFocus/> in your XML layout.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            edittext.requestFocus();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textId);
editText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `<requestFocus/>` tag in the `EditText` like:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="25dp" >

        <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: and if you wish you may change the focus from 1st to 5th box anytime without handling your java code because it works in your layout XML